# Breeze Json Serialization using WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am pretty new to Breeze, and working on a project that is Breeze on the client side and ASP.NET Web API 2 on the server side.  I have employed all of the best practices listed on the Breeze website (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller).

But one question I have is why does every data node list the .NET type of the object when the items are serialized.  Whenever I get a list with a significant number of records, I might see the majority of the data being the $type entity, listing the full class namespace and the assembly name.  This $type entity is repeated for every data node, which code be 100's of repetitions.

It seems it would be more logical and save on the payload of the breeze call to do something similar to what namespaces do in Xml serialization on the server side.  Possibly listing the full class signatures in a header, while the objects only have a shortcut to the full definition in the header.  Such as:

Header:

```
$typeFull: {
key: 'ABC',
namespace: 'ABCCompany.Data.Client.ViewModels.Customers'
```

Data:

$id: 1,
$typeKey: 'abc',

Here is an example of the current data returned to breeze:

```
[
{
$id: "1",
$type: "Assembly.Root, ABCCompany.Data.Client.ViewModels.Customers",
CustomerId: 1,
Name: "ABC Company",
LongDescription: "Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me!  Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me! Describe me!",
Phone: "800-555-1212",
PrimaryContactName: "Bugs Bunny",
AddressId: 1,
Address: {
$id: "2",
$type: "Assembly.Location, ABCCompany.Data.Client.ViewModels.Customers.Addresses",
AddressLine1: "2600 Red Box Blvd",
AddressLine2: null,
City: "Anaheim",
StateId: 35,
Zip: "44122",
CountryCode: "US",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on the breeze dev team so I can't answer for them but here's my 2 cents:

In practice the redundant information doesn't matter because the data will be gzipped.  Here's how to ensure the json is compressed (assuming you're using IIS):

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression

Comment: Not a fan of the idea of depending on compression to make up for a shortcoming. Why do you say that the data "will be gzipped", when that isn't the default practice?  Until that setup occurs, it won't be zipped

Comment: Again, my opinion here:  I don't think this is a shortcoming.  Consider the tags in the json from your example: "CustomerId", "AddressLine1", etc.  These are repeated when you have "100's of repetitions".  In practice they make up at least 50% of the data.  If this were xml the percentage would be even higher.  Json and xml are used every day with the understanding that compression will balance the descriptiveness of the format.  Compression is a necessity and the breeze type info is inconsequential.